# Is there a Run/Debug Configuration template for ASP Classic for Jetbrains Rider?

Tags: asp-classic, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have an ASP Classic / VBScript project that I want to run with IIS Express when pressing the Run or Debug buttons in Rider, as one can when using Visual Studio. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think JetBrains bothers itself to support obsolete technologies like that.

Comment: There is a plugin for Bash files. It provides custom Run/Debug Configuration that allows you to run such files from IDE. There is one for Cmd files .. but I do not know if it provides Run/Debug Configurations. If it does (or some another plugin offers similar functionality)... you could write some custom `.cmd` file that will launch the needed commands for you (e.g. launch IIS Express; open specific URL in a browser). No better ideas from me. P.S. You could use External Tools functionality, but AFAIK it's IDE-wide functionality and not project-specific...

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Classic ASP needs IIS to run. IIS Express (cassini) does not support classic ASP. You can map a website or website's folder to a directory and open that in JetBrains for editing and testing. That is how Dreamweaver and other Classic ASP editing tools used to work back in the day and you can probably use visual studio code for that today.

Also, if you have not already done so, please check out [This Link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207077405-ASP-Support-VBScript-JScript-)

Comment: IIS Express does support Classic ASP.

Comment: Even so, if you are trying to debug, you can map your IIS root to a directory and open with JetBrains, make the changes and call the URL in browser since its scripts and not compiled code